# How To Convert A Number To an ASCII Character?

Tags: c#, windows, function, winforms, ascii

I want to create an application where user would input a number and the program will throw back a character to the user.

Edit: How about vice versa, changing a ascii character into number?

Comment: Please don't edit a question after there are answers to make it a new question (in this case the inverse).  Open a new question.

Answer (score 51):

You can use one of these methods to convert number to an **ASCII / Unicode / UTF-16** character:

You can use these methods convert the value of the specified 32-bit signed integer to its Unicode character:

```
char c = (char)65;
char c = Convert.ToChar(65);
```

Also, [`ASCII.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8(v=vs.110).aspx) decodes a range of bytes from a byte array into a string:

```
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{ 65 });
```

Keep in mind that, `ASCIIEncoding` does not provide error detection. Any byte greater than hexadecimal 0x7F is decoded as the Unicode question mark ("?").

Comment: Great example, this should be the voted upon answer!

Comment: from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hxt0028(v=vs.80).aspx i need the char with Dec value 150 and Hex 96...i have tried all 3 of the above but doesnt return me the right character..:/

Answer (score 5):

Edit: By request, I added a check to make sure the value entered was within the ASCII range of 0 to 127.  Whether you want to limit this is up to you. In C# (and I believe .NET in general), `char`s are represented using UTF-16, so any valid UTF-16 character value could be cast into it.  However, it is possible a system does not know what every Unicode character should look like so it may show up incorrectly.

```
// Read a line of input
string input = Console.ReadLine();

int value;
// Try to parse the input into an Int32
if (Int32.TryParse(input, out value)) {
    // Parse was successful
    if (value >= 0 and value < 128) {
        //value entered was within the valid ASCII range
        //cast value to a char and print it
        char c = (char)value;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but you'd need to set some minimum/maximum bounds for your integer input. Not all numbers convert to displayable ASCII characters.

Comment: How about converting ascii characters into number?

Comment: @CyraxNguyen: You can simply cast the other way. `int i = (int)'a';`  This will put the ascii value of the letter `a` in `i`.

Answer (score 5):

To get ascii to a number, you would just cast your char value into an integer.

```
char ascii = 'a'
int value = (int)ascii
```

Variable value will now have 97 which corresponds to the value of that ascii character

(Use this link for reference)
http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Answer (score 2):

you can simply cast it.

```
char c = (char)100;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was googling about how to convert an int to char, that got me here. But my question was to convert for example int of 6 to char of '6'.
For those who came here like me, this is how to do it:

```
int num = 6;
num.ToString().ToCharArray()[0];
```

Comment: Or simply `num + '0'`

Answer (score 1):

C# represents a character in UTF-16 coding rather than ASCII. Therefore converting a integer to character do not make any difference for A-Z and a-z. But I was working with ASCII Codes besides alphabets and number which did not work for me as system uses UTF-16 code. Therefore I browsed UTF-16 code for all UTF-16 character. Here is the module :

```
void utfchars()
{
 int i, a, b, x;
 ConsoleKeyInfo z;
  do
  {
   a = 0; b = 0; Console.Clear();
    for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
     if (b == 20)
     {
      b = 0;
      a = a + 1;
     }
    Console.SetCursorPosition((a * 15) + 1, b + 1);
    Console.Write("{0} == {1}", i, (char)i);
   b = b+1;
   if (i % 100 == 0)
  {
 Console.Write("\n\t\t\tPress any key to continue {0}", b);
 a = 0; b = 0;
 Console.ReadKey(true); Console.Clear();
 }
}
Console.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tPress any key to Repeat and E to exit");
z = Console.ReadKey();
if (z.KeyChar == 'e' || z.KeyChar == 'E') Environment.Exit(0);
} while (1 == 1);
}
```