# Converting number to character

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

the following code converts characters A-Z to a number between 1 and 26, all are upper case for simplicity.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        foreach (char c in letters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c +" = " + CharToNumber(c));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static int CharToNumber(char character)
    {
        // index starts at 0, 65 is the ascii code for A hence the program -64 so start at 1 therefore A=1
         return (int)Char.ToUpper(character) - 64;
    }

    static char NumberToChar(int number)
    {
        //  code here
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to do the same but vice versa, so convert that number back to the same character. I am unsure on where to start. Any idea much appreciated, thank you

Comment: I'm not an expert at C#, but maybe `(char) (number + 64)`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's entirely pointless to implement character conversion incorrectly (encodings, etc.)

Comment: You should be able just to cast it: `static char NumberToChar(int number)
    {
       return (char) number;
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation is just

```
static char NumberToChar(int number)
{
    return (char) ('A' + number - 1); // "- 1" : You want to start from 1
}
```

Correspondingly

```
static int CharToNumber(char character) 
{
    return character - 'A' + 1; // " + 1" : You want to start from 1
}
```

Note, that in C# `char` is in fact a *16-bit integer* so you can just *convert* it.

Edit: according to your prior code you also want to modify the `Main(string[] args)`:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
     ...
     // Reverse 
     for (int i = 1; i <= 26; ++i)
       Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + NumberChar(i));
       Console.ReadLine();
     } 
   }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, could you tell me what I would put in the 'main' for that to take effect/display?

Comment: @peter.k: you have to update\modify `Main(string[] args)` slightly (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast directly from an integer to a character, which returns the character with the corresponding Unicode value. The Unicode value for `A` is 65, and the rest of the English alphabet continues in order, so you could just add 64 to your number and return the Unicode character. There are [a number of ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730706/how-to-convert-a-number-to-an-ascii-character).

If you don't want to hard-code the Unicode offset you can do this trick:

```
static char NumberToChar(int number)
{
    int offset = (int)'A' - 1;
    return (char)(number + offset);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, could you tell me what I would put in the 'main' for that to take effect/display?