# Make a line of code more elegant

Tags: c#

I need to convert an unicode to letter and then paste the letter into a textbox. So I have a code like this:

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(letter_code));
```

I think this code line doesn't look good and there's another way to do the same thing. Is it?

Comment: What's `letter_code`? (And as an aside, I'd suggest that you start to follow the .NET naming conventions - which would use `letterCode` instead of `letter_code`.)

Comment: It's an integer value

Comment: Purely off the top of my head... Might be way off, isn't there an Encoding.Unicode.GetString() that can do this?

Comment: `textBox1.Text = new string(letter_code,1); `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730706/how-to-convert-a-number-to-an-ascii-character

Comment: So its compile-time type is `int`? (It would have been easier if you'd provided a short but complete program to start with...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `letter_code` is of type `int`, I'd probably cast to `char` and call `ToString`:

```
textBox1.Text = ((char) letter_code).ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain me, why use `.ToString ()` when `Convert.ToString` is safer? I mean, not in this particular case. Just wondering))

Comment: @JohnGreen The difference between the two is that one handles null while the other doesn't. your using a char and int which can't be null

Comment: ToString() is not inherently unsafe.  It is a method inherited from object.  Here it is using the override of that method as defined for data type char.  You could override that method to be anything you want it to be.

Comment: @JohnGreen: I *usually* use `ToString` to convert a value to a string. That's what it's there for, after all. If a the value I want to convert may be null, I usually think about that separately - but it's not going to happen for a `char`.